# SQL Server: replace constant values with name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query:

```
Select * 
from table 
where value = 1
```

but the value is used in a lot of places

and I want to use something like:

```
userValue = 1

Select * 
from table 
where  value = $userValue
```

Is something like that feasible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use a value at lots of places use:

```
Declare @uservalue INT

SET @uservalue = 1

Select * from table where  value= @uservalue
```

Below link provide the details on how to use local variables:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258839%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Also these are all basics. Try to find it by your own.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**`Declare`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188927.aspx) a variable and `store` the `value` in that variable.

`Variable`s are declared in the body of a batch or procedure with the `DECLARE statement` and are assigned values by using either a `SET or SELECT statement`. After declaration, all variables are initialized as `NULL`, unless a value is provided as part of the declaration.

```
Declare @uservalue int =1

Select * from table where  value= @uservalue
```